# Spring boot- Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported. Use create() or register() directly instead

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, netflix-zuul

I am building a spring boot microservices application but getting this error when I open in intellij idea.

```
Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported. Use create() or register() directly instead. You attempted to replace a task named 'ZuulServerApplication.main()', but there is no existing task with that name.
```

I have other projects downloaded from [Spring Boot Initialzr](https://start.spring.io/) they didn't show any error but recently I am getting this issue. How to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This used to be a deprecated behavior that was finally made an error in `Gradle-6.0`. Its a known bug which should be solved if you can upgrade to the 2019.3 EAP or beta. In my experience if you change your gradle wrapper to `5.6.4` should solve this problem.

Just to clarify as to where the change should be made in the spring boot app. In the app under gradle/wrapper folder you would find gradle-wrapper.properties. Update the distribution url as `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` or any other source where you can find the appropriate gradle zip file.

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip and its still not working

Comment: You need to downgrade gradle. Try `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip`

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks!